# Dyanamic 2d array in C++ using double pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix, pointer-to-pointer

I have the following code, I made sure I did everything as explained in [Pointer-to-pointer dynamic two-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001803/pointer-to-pointer-dynamic-two-dimensional-array)

I need my 2d matrix to be dyanmic i.e the user needs to enter the dimensions. But I am getting error in my cin when taking the input form the user. whats wrong with the following code?

```
int numberOfRows, numberOfColumn;
cout << "Please enter the number of rows: ";
cin >> numberOfRows;
cout << endl << "Please enter the number of columns ";
cin >> numberOfColumn;


int** matrix= new int*[numberOfRows];

for (int i=0; i<numberOfRows; i++)
{
    matrix[numberOfRows]= new int[numberOfColumn];
}

for (int i=0; i<numberOfRows; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<numberOfColumn; j++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter Row " << (i+1) << " Column "<< (j+1) <<" element: ";
        cin>> matrix[i][j];
        cout << endl;
    }
}

for (int i=0; i<numberOfRows; i++)
{

    for(int j=0; j<numberOfColumn; j++)
    {
        cout << matrix[i][j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While allocating memory in for loop

```
matrix[i]= new int[numberOfColumn]; 
     instead of matrix[numberOfRows]= new int[numberOfColumn];
```

Note:you also need to free the allocated memory

corrected code

http://ideone.com/ILw1qa

Comment: Yes I will free the allocated memory. I cannot believe that I made just a crappy mistake. Thank you much, I would have never seen that.

Comment: To  free the allocated memory do I just delete [] matrix or do I need to do a loop and delete very int* pointed by matrix then delete matrix itself?

Answer (score 2):

You have this:

```
  for (int i=0; i<numberOfRows; i++)
  {
      matrix[numberOfRows]= new int[numberOfColumn];
  }
```

Should be:

```
  for (int i=0; i<numberOfRows; i++)
  {
      matrix[i]= new int[numberOfColumn];
  }
```

Notice that the `matrix[numberOfRows]` changed to `matrix[i]`

Comment: It always helps to get a second pair of eyes on something when you get stuck. I'm glad I could help.