# What does asterisk before brackets on object creation mean in C++?

Tags: c++, asterisk, indirection

I was reading an example of a hash table implementation in C++ from a website and saw this.

```
private:
  HashEntry **table;
public:
  HashMap() {
        table = new HashEntry*[TABLE_SIZE];
        for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
              table[i] = NULL;
  }
```

The line with the syntax I don't understand is:

```
table = new HashEntry*[TABLE_SIZE];
```

What does it mean to have the asterisk before the brackets like that?

Comment: well it means it's an array of `HashEntry*` of size `TABLE_SIZE`

Comment: you can read this for some reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001803/pointer-to-pointer-dynamic-two-dimensional-array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`new HashEntry*[TABLE_SIZE]` allocates and constructs an array of `TABLE_SIZE` elements, where each element is a `HashEntry*`, i.e. a pointer to a `HashEntry`.

A more modern C++ version of that would be:

```
private:
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<HashEntry>> table;
public:
  HashMap() : table(TABLE_SIZE) {}
```

This avoids having to define your own destructor, and is generally safer.

Comment: And automatically sets everything in it to NULL I assume?

Comment: @James4701: unique_ptr (and other smart pointers generally) is "null" by default, yes.  This is contrary to raw C pointers which are uninitialized by default.

Answer (score 0):

The asterisk indicates that it is a pointer

Here are some links

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson6.html

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointers.htm

http://www.augustcouncil.com/~tgibson/tutorial/ptr.html