# Why am I getting a segmentation fault for this multidimensional array?

Tags: c++

I want to create a 2D pointer boolean array, but as soon as I declare it and try to initialize it I get a segmentation fault. I tried only declaring the array and not initializing it, and I've tried initializing the array as well.

I have some functions and global variables in my program, and have tried making everything except my main function, #include , and using namespace std; into a comment but I'm still getting the error: 
only declaring:

```
int main(){
    // Variable declarations. You can add more if necessary
    bool **world;
    int nrows, ncols;
    char next;

    cout << "Enter world dimensions (rows and columns): ";
    cin >> nrows >> ncols;


    **world = new bool*[ncols];
    for (int   i = 0; i < ncols; i++) {
      world[i] = new bool[nrows];
    }
```

declaring and initializing:

```
int main(){
    // Variable declarations. You can add more if necessary
    bool **world;
    int nrows, ncols;
    char next;

    cout << "Enter world dimensions (rows and columns): ";
    cin >> nrows >> ncols;


    **world = new bool*[ncols];
    for (int   i = 0; i < ncols; i++) {
      world[i] = new bool[nrows];
    }   
    for (int i = 0; i < ncols; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < nrows; ++j) {
        world[i][j] = false;
      }
    }
```

The error is: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

Comment: In C++ you should steer towards solutions using `std::vector` and well away from manual allocations using `new[]`.

Comment: `**world = new bool*[ncols];` -- this doesn't do what you think it does. Does your C++ compiler warn you about this line?

Comment: unfortunately my compiler isn't giving me any warnings, only the error message. I'm curious what that code does in actuality?

Comment: It would behoove you to implement a simple (i.e. one-dimensional) array before you attempt this.

Comment: It's for an assignment, unfortunately it is necessary for the assignment to use a 2D array

Comment: In addition to what @SamVarshavchik said, many compilers let you tune what warnings they produce. For example, for `gcc` you could pass `-Wall` to see all warnings and `-Werr` to treat any warning as an error. Anyway, as @SamVarshavchik implies the fix is `world = new bool*[ncols];` - you want to make `world`, point to the newly allocated array of pointers to boolean.

Comment: Perhaps this question will have some answers that would help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001803/pointer-to-pointer-dynamic-two-dimensional-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001803/pointer-to-pointer-dynamic-two-dimensional-array)

Comment: `**world = new bool*[ncols];` should give an error message, if you don't see one then adjust your compiler settings

Comment: Thank you all, will be adjusting my compiler and the solution works

Comment: Also note - per your prompt, you are using `ncols` in place of `nrows` and vice-versa throughout your code. If you want a `rows x cols` dynamic array of `bool`, you need: `world = new bool*[nrows];` and then loop allocating `world[i] = new bool[ncols];`. Otherwise you are creating a `ncols x nrows` collection of `bool`.

Answer (score 1):

`**world = new bool*[ncols];` is equivalent to `world[0][0] = new bool*[ncols];` as world is uninitialised this is undefined behaviour. This only complies as a pointer is convertible to bool. If your array was a different type like `int` your code wouldn't compile.

What you actually want to do is assign to the pointer:

```
world = new bool*[ncols];
```

A  `std::vector` would make your code simpler and safer, this single line replaces all your initialisation code and has no memory leaks:

```
std::vector<std::vector<bool>> world(ncols, std::vector<bool>(nrows, false));
```

I'm general multidimensional arrays and vectors have poor performance, you are better off using a single dimensional array and calculating the index with: `col  * nrows + row`